# Newton's method with exact line search is of order two convergence.

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

How to prove Newton's method with exact line search is of order two convergence?

Namely, let $f \in C^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and assume that $x^*=\arg \min f(x)$ and $F(x^*)$ is positive definite, where $F$ is the Hessian of $f$. $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha_k d_k,$ $d_k=-\left[F\left({x}_{k}\right)\right]^{-1} \nabla f\left({x}_{k}\right)^{T}$, where $\alpha_k=\arg \min_\alpha f(x_k+\alpha d_k)$. How to prove the order of convergence of this algorithm is at least two?

I know that Newton's method with $\alpha_k=1$ is of order two convergence so I'm trying to prove that $\alpha_k \to 1$. Since $\alpha_k=\arg \min_\alpha f(x_k+\alpha d_k)$, we have $\nabla f(x_k+\alpha_k d_k) d_k^T=0$. Take the derivative of $d_k$ on both sides we get $\alpha_k F(x_k+\alpha_k d_k)d^T_k+\nabla f(x_k+\alpha_k d_k) =0$. I don't know what to do next.

Any ideas? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.